# Multiple text fields in a single query using group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, text, field, group-concat

I'm new to MySQL, and am using it to manage a database of books. Each book has, in addition to its standard data and description, some miscellaneous text fields, which may depend on the book. For example a book might have a few reviews, links, etc.

I thought I'd store these in a table with the book_id, the field type (for example review), and the field contents.

Now, my problem is that when I obtain all the data for a single book, I'd like to optimize the query. It'd be simple enough to get all the additional text field data with a second query. However, would there be a significant performance gain if I were to use group_concat to give me all the book information, including these additional text fields, in a single query?

This means I'd also have to make sure my separator character is escaped, and I'd have to unescape it after obtaining the data. Which approach would work better for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Get the data that you need, and don't try to second-guess the DB's query strategy. If you have thousands of records and there's really a bottleneck, you can think about adding suitable indices.

Comment: I didn't put it quite right I suppose - this is a new database I'm creating for a website, and so I'd like to start things off the right way.

Comment: Oh, OK. Make sure the database is normalized. All else will fall into place. Don't try to implement your own mini database inside a field.

Comment: The database is normalized, at least to the level I know of. Basically, lets say you have a table of books with a book_id, name, author_id, and so on.. I may want to have many reviews for each book. So I have a table of reviews, with a review_id, book_id, source, and content. Now, when I'm pulling book data, would it be more efficient to run a separate query for getting the reviews, or pulling everything in one query using a group_concat (which I'm not sure about using because the reviews may be large in size and I'd have to escape the separator)

Comment: Right. See my first comment. Pull out the data in the way that you need it. There's no point mangling it into some format that you have to parse again later, which amounts to writing your own mini-database.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT is normally an excellent way of making reporting easier. But for fields containing a lot of text, this will easily lead to right truncated data (chopped off after e.g. 1024 characters depending on you my.cnf setting group_concat_max_len ). Worse, if the field(s) that are GROUP_CONCAT'ed is of type BLOB (TEXT, LONGTEXT etc) there will be a lot of RW to disk as temptables. However if the fields that you GROUP_CONCAT'ing are VARCHAR or INT, you may create huge reports straight from index cached data using only a single query instead of multiple, which may be a performance boost.

example

```
SELECT 
    B.bookID, 
    B.bookTitle, 
    B.isbn, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            (IFNULL(R.review, "no reviews of this book")), 
            R.revierName)
        ORDER BY R.stars 
        SEPARATOR "<br />"
    ) AS reviews
FROM books B
LEFT JOIN reviews R ON (B.bookID = R.bookID)
;
```

PS correct me if I'm wrong about how MySQL caches data from aggregated queries.